# Get a result of a predefined query by one click?

Tags: query

In my SharePoint site, I see a search box at the top of navigation bar left side of the page. I want to avoid manually typing 
frequently-used query strings (e.g. filename:meeting). Instead, I want to have a link or something such that if you click it, you get a result of the predefined query.

Answer (score 3):

If you do that Search query from the search center then you can use the resulting url. It will look something like:

```
[url for your search center]?k="search term"
```